# HTML Form - Input Type hidden with PHP post input not working

Tags: php, html

Clarification:

I have a form let say like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.example.at/example/" id="comparison">
<input type="radio" id="region" name="region" value="austria">
<input type="radio" id="region" name="region" value="germany">
<input type="radio" id="tarif" name="tarif" value="Basis">
<input type="radio" id="tarif" name="tarif" value="Comfort">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="compare">
</form>
```

User can submit - working finely.

On a second page (https://www.example.at/example/) I want to pick up the variable **region**. But I would like the user to again be able to switch between Basis and Comfort. So value **region** does **not to be entered again.**

```
<form method="post" id="comparison2">
<input type="hidden" name="region" id="region" value="<?php echo_POST['region']; ?>" />
<input type="radio" id="tarif" name="tarif" value="Basis">
<input type="radio" id="tarif" name="tarif" value="Comfort">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="compare">
</form>
```

So if I echo the php with **region** it gives me the correct value outside of the form. Altough after submitting the second form it triggers a php shortcode(again) with the submit again where it displays a € value from our database.

But even though it worked properly with the input entered by the user(first step) it doesn't use or differently use the hidden input.

If it helps: I'm currently testing here: https://www.krankenversichern.at/testing-environment/

Comment: So what version of code does not work? Why not storing values to session instead?

Comment: *"the output in another shortcode does not trigger the expected result"* - It's not clear to me what you mean by that.  Can you be more specific about the problem?  Is the value being included in the form element when you examine the page source?  Is that element part of the form?  Is the value posted when the form is submitted?  What specifically fails?

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: "in a shortcode" — Shortcodes are not a PHP thing. They are a WordPress thing. Are you writing a WordPress extension?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: In the clarification... When you examine the page source for your hidden input, is the expected value present?

Comment: Unfortunately it only shows the php code - not the actual value itself. I really don't know why tough.

Comment: @SebastianArthofer: If you're seeing the PHP code in your browser then that would be a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5121495/328193

Comment: So is this a TYPO - echo_POST['region'];

Comment: `<?php echo_POST['region']; ?>` - is not a typo from my side - i found this piece of code on another stackoverflow post

Comment: So I'm using elementor as a page builder, could it be that the php within the elementor html widget won't work?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was: I took all of my html code and put it in a shortcode. I used the php echo as suggested and used the text element widget in elementor. That's it. Took probably 2 minutes!